# "go: go.mod file not found in current directory" but it already exist in the directory

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a DockerFile for a project around GCP.
I'm using go version 1.17 and it fails at the get command saying that go.mod isn't found but it exist in the same directory as the Dockerfile. I already tried `go mod init` and `go mod tidy` but I still got the same error. Here are my env variables and my files :

```
GO111MODULE="auto"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/name/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/name/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/name/work/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/name/work"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.17.1"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/home/name/workspace/professional-services/tools/gcs2bq/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build3855548593=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

list of the files in my working directory :

```
name@vm-gcs2bq:~/workspace/professional-services/tools/gcs2bq$ ls
Dockerfile  bigquery.schema   datastudio.png           gcs2bq.avsc  go.mod  main.go
README.md   credentials.json  gcs2bq-custom-role.yaml  gcs2bq.yaml  go.sum  run.sh
```

My working directory in the Dockerfile is correctly set (the gcs2bq one) and when trying to build it I got :

```
Step 6/16 : RUN go get -v ./...
 ---> Running in ebaa284887cf
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
```

I'm still kinda new to go, mostly did c and python and I read that packages are managed in a different way in this language but I think I set my paths correctly too. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Any help is appreciated, ask for more details if you need to.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try to set GO111MODULE to auto again. `go env -w GO111MODULE=auto`

Comment: If the `go.mod` is missing, it means you are either not copying it into the container, or are in a different directory. I'm not sure what you intend for `go get -v ./...` to do, you probably want `go install`.

Comment: What are you trying to *download* with `go get -v ./...`?

Comment: What's in your Dockerfile?  Are you `COPY`ing the `go.mod` file into the correct place?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
Here is the repo of what I want to use : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/main/tools/gcs2bq

@Ashok Tried it, still in auto mode, didn't seems to help to build.
@JimB @mkopriva I'm not sure either with the ./... part but isn't it a way to download every packages/ depedencies used in the directory ? I tried to use ```go install``` instead but still got he missing go.mod error.

Comment: Here is the content of my Dockerfile right now ;

FROM golang:1.17

ENV GOPATH=/home/name/work
ENV GOROOT=/usr/local/go

WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/rosmo/gcs2bq

COPY main.go .

#RUN go get -v ./... 
RUN go install
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o /gcs2bq .

FROM google/cloud-sdk:slim
WORKDIR /
RUN chown -R 1000 /home
COPY --from=0 /gcs2bq .
COPY gcs2bq.avsc .
COPY bigquery.schema .
COPY run.sh .
RUN chmod +x run.sh
CMD ["/run.sh"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I solved my problem.

First, my WORKDIR wasn't pointing at the right directory : `WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/rosmo/gcs2bq` instead of `WORKDIR /work/src/github.com/rosmo/gcs2bq` but it's only because of me using /work instead of /go for the installed packages.

Then I added the follwing after the `COPY main.go .` command :

```
RUN  go mod init v1
RUN go mod tidy
```

Which created the "missing" go.mod file and properly installed the dependencies/packages needed.

The rest of the build went perfectly normal.

Thanks for your help.